# Длинное предложение

Tags: общие-вопросы

Несколькими страницами раннее я уже обращался к этому вопросу, однако, логического завершения он не получил. 
Суть в том, чтобы составить максимально длинное предложение без знаков препинания (за исключением точки в конце). Отдельно подчеркиваю, что в задачу не ставится читабельность и простота восприятия текста. Единственное, что следует соблюсти, так это осмысленность текста.

Совместно с участниками форума, удалось составить такое предложение:

"В кипельно-белой сверкающей под серебристым светом холодных звёзд накидке с мягким узким меховым подбоем из непроглядного едва шевелящегося мрака сладко засыпающего тронного зала сквозь наполненный крикливыми волнистыми попугаями и заставленный сосудами с диковинными растениями коридор и словно омертвевшую к вечернему часу лоджию неуклюже тянущейся хромой походкой двадцать четвёртого числа предпоследнего зимнего месяца торжественно и важно прошествовал пучеглазый сановитый жирный заместитель начальника третьего конного отряда персидской армии пожилой и мудрый визирь Аль Харрез Пуль ибн Хасан с длинной наградной саблей с круглым золотистым навершием изогнутой рукояти в прижатой к груди загоревшей руке".

1) Я не уверен, что в этом предложении действительно не требуются знаки препинания. Просьба: если требуются, указать где, а так же, дать совет, можно ли обойти эту необходимость?

2) Как дополнение к основному вопросу. Отдельно буду признателен тем, кто порекомендует как ещё удлинить данное предложение.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что есть запятая после "кипельно-белой".

Answer (score 2):

И после непроглядного.

Comment: Ну а помимо однородных?